# Messaging - Why Entity Bean or Session Bean not suitable

Tags: ejb, jms

For messaging system/ handling message - use MDB; don't use Entity Bean or Session Bean. Please provide me the reason.

Thanks in Adv 
RW

Answer (score 0):

An MDB is designed to accept messages whereas the others aren't.  From [an old Sun tutorial](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/tutorial/1_3-fcs/doc/EJBConcepts5.html) but [still the same in the up to date version](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipko.html)

> The most visible difference between message-driven beans and session
>   and entity beans is that clients do not access message-driven beans
>   through interfaces. Interfaces are described in the section Defining
>   Client Access with Interfaces. Unlike a session or entity bean, a
>   message-driven bean has only a bean class

and

> Session beans allow you to send JMS messages and to receive them
>   synchronously but not asynchronously. To avoid tying up server
>   resources, do not to use blocking synchronous receives in a
>   server-side component; in general, JMS messages should not be sent or
>   received synchronously. To receive messages asynchronously, use a
>   message-driven bean.

In other words: in a Session bean you can only receive a message when the bean was called.  The app server will automatically call the onMessage method of the MDB attached to the destination (Queue or Topic) on which a message was received.  This means that MDBs will be guaranteed to handle each message as soon it's available, something that you can't guarantee with session beans.